# Why isn't ssh-agent a background process by default?

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, ssh-agent

I have always wondered why such a basic feature (loading ssh keys for persistent usage) requires a clunky command to execute in the background of a cmdline. Why isn't ssh-agent a service (for example) by default? I assume there might be a security reason, but I'm curious to get other thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `ssh-agent` an attacker can get the unencrypted key from memory. See https://www.netspi.com/blog/technical/network-penetration-testing/stealing-unencrypted-ssh-agent-keys-from-memory/

Answer (score 0):

If `ssh-agent` is not running by default, the packager and system administrator have not set it up for you. As this is a matter of personal preference and important to security, not enabled by default makes sense to me. How tos exist of how to set it up in many environments.

`ssh-agent` usage of printing out shell variables to evaluate is not typical of most programs.

Other ssh agents may be have a friendlier experience. For example, on the desktop there exists [Gnome Keyring SSH Agent](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GnomeKeyring/Ssh).